# getConnectionInfo() exception

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-wifi

Given this code:

```
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
```

...and this line in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I still get the exception:

```
WifiService: Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
```

I am debugging on a Xoom, Honeycomb 3.1.

If there is any other info that is needed, please ask.

EDIT: added Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.WiFiDemo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="WiFiDemo">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please mark one of the answers as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.WiFiDemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"     android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="WiFiDemo">            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: And make sure the <uses-permission... is a direct child of the manifest-Tag.

Comment: @Thommy, By direct child, I assumed you meant outside of the application tag. Adding the Network State permission did not work; same error.

Comment: Manifest was added to original message.

Comment: please mark the question as answered.  if none of our answered did it then please post your own answer and mark it as such

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.WiFiDemo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="WiFiDemo">
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```